# Using Koin in multi-module Android Project

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin

I've a multi-module project & I'm facing some weird issues setting up Koin DI. My project has following modules: `app`, `library`.

I've declared an interface in `library` module & its corresponding implementation in `app` module & I want to use the same in library. The code looks somewhat like:

**Library Module:**

```
interface Storage {
    fun setUser(user: User)
    fun getUser(): User
}
```

**App Module:**

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin(this, listOf(appModule))
} 


val appModule = module {
    single<Storage> { AppStorage(androidApplication()) }
}
```

Now, when I try to inject `Storage` in library module, I get `NoBeanDefFoundException`. Below is the code for the same:

```
class LibActivity {

    private val storage by inject<Storage>()
    ...
}
```

Any ideas on what is wrong with the above code?

Comment: Should work something like that. What version of koin are you using? The `startKoin` syntax looks like koin 1; koin 2 is also available.

Comment: @Gaurav Arora, Were you able to fix the issue, please let me know